# Como convertir este algoritmo en hibernate de actualizacion en una funcion encapsulada

Tags: java, hibernate

me gustaria saber como transformar este algoritmo en una funcion al estilo **funcion_actualizar(param1,param2,...)** , quiero decir,  encapsular la el algoritmo en una funcion.

A continuacion os dejo lo que tengo.

```
Object obj4 = s.load(Empleados.class, new Integer(103));    // 103 record exists
Empleados emp = (Empleados) obj4;

    emp.setSname("Reddy");
    emp.setSmarks(99);
    session.update(s5);
    tx1.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo crearía una interfaz que implementasen todas las entidades y que declarara los métodos "set" que estás utilizando en el algoritmo. De esta forma al método le pasarías un objeto de esa interfaz y un Integer. Quedaría así:

Interfaz para todas las entidades:

```
public interface Entidad {

    public setSName(String name);    
    public setSmarks(Intger smarks);
}
```

Despues en tu clase Empleados implementas la interfaz y escribes los métodos "set". Acuerdate de poner las anotaciones **@Override**

```
public class Empleados implements Entidad {

    private String SName;
    private Integer SMarkcs;

    /**
     * @return the SName;
     */
    public String getSName() {
        return SName;
    }

    /**
     * @param SName the SName to set
     */
    @Override
    public void setSName(String SName) {
        this.SName = SName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the SMarkcs;
     */
    public Integer getSMarkcs() {
        return SMarkcs;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSmarks(Integer smarks) {
        this.SMarkcs = smarks;
    }
}
```

Finalmente tu algoritmo quedaría encapsulado en un método así:

```
public void update(Class entidad, Integer id, String name, Integer marks) {

        Object obj4 = s.load(entidad, id);    // 103 record exists
    Entidad emp = (Entidad) obj4;

    emp.setSName(name);
    emp.setSmarks(marks);
    session.update(emp);
    tx1.commit();

    }
```

Y lo llamarías así: `update(Empleados.class, 103, "Reddy", 99);`